# How to call a function when we have its arguments in an array

Tags: javascript, function, arguments

Let's say we have a function

```
f = function(a, b, c){
    // do something important
}
```

and an array containing the arguments

```
var args = [5, 'string', 12] // just any values
```

Obviously, I could call my function like this :

```
f(args[0], args[1], args[2])
```

This is really not elegant, and I look for a better way to accomplish this. Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: You'll want to see [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) and [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply); in particular, `apply` applies here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`.apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply). The second argument lets you specify an array of arguments to the function you are trying to call. The first argument is the value of `this` you want in the context of the function.

So in your case it would be:

```
f.apply(null, args);
```

or

```
f.apply(window, args);
```

If you want `this` within the context of `f` to be the `window` object.

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for [Function.apply()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)

```
f.apply(window, args); // pass something other than null to set 'this' within the call
```

Comment: note that you can't use apply() if you use "new ", you'll have to manually fill-in the parameters until ES6 is widely supported.

Comment: @dandavis: Or `var o = Object.create(f.prototype); f.apply(o, args);`

Answer (score 1):

Use `.apply()`.

```
f.apply(window, args);
```

This will work with any array-like object in the second argument position.

It invokes the function `f`, and sets the first argument you pass as its `this` value *(here I just used `window`)*, and distributes the members of the second argument as individual arguments to the function.

The result is as though you had done this:

```
f(5, 'string', 12);
```

---

There's a counterpart to the `Function.prototype.apply` method called `.call()`. The `.call()` method is exactly the same, except that you pass the arguments individually.

```
f.call(window, 5, 'string, 12);
```

The purpose of this is the call the function like normal, but set the `this` value manually.

Answer (score -1):

It depends of your needs (of course)

if elements are homogenous

```
var sum = function(numbers) {
   // do some calculations
}

var randomees = [5, 6, 12]
var total = sum(randomees);
```

If they are not, they should have some kind of description. I.e. if you are defining options or parameters, then you would consider this

```
var parameters = {
    size:13,
    shipped:true,
    description:"Laptop"
}

var displayLaptop = function(characteristics) {
    console.log(characteristics.size)
}
```

(or even play with some jQuery.extend ish method)